# Laravel3 group_by + sum + paginate?

Tags: mysql, laravel, pagination, laravel-3

I have to write a query like : `SELECT azon, SUM(points) points FROM stats GROUP BY azon;`
Also I need to paginate them in Laravel3.

So I tried `Stats::group_by('azon')->sum('points')->paginate(20);`. Of course this did not work. So I tried

```
$stats2 = DB::table('stats')
                ->select('azon', DB::raw('SUM(points) as points'))
                ->group_by('azon')
                ->paginate(20);
```

No results. 
The last thing I tried was `DB::query('SELECT azon, SUM(points) points FROM test_stats GROUP BY azon')` but this returns an array and I cannot paginate an array. 
Any ideas, workarounds. I hope Laravel3 has something for this as this is a basic query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue with your query is, **select** function in **Query Builder** accepts array parameter.

```
$stats2 = DB::table('stats')
    ->select( array( 'azon', DB::raw('SUM(points) as points') ) )
    ->group_by('azon')
    ->paginate(20);
```